# How to put an item in a dispenser with a commandblock

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

so I was just messing around when my friend asked me to be able to take armor off and replace it in a dispenser with a command, the take a way part is easy but replace that a whole different challenge

I was wonder how I do that 
PS specifically in **slot 5**

Answer (score 1):

You can put it in like this:

> /replaceitem block x y z slot.hotbar.0 minecraft:item

Place the coordinates of the block in x y z and change the number after slot.hotbar to change where it goes, 0 being in the top left and 8 in the bottom right. Replace the item after minecraft to what item you want in there.

Answer (score 0):

There's multiple ways of doing this.

1. Not needing enchanted stuff. Use `testfor` to find out what type of armor it is
2. Getting the item some way. Teleport the item to a hopper running into the dispenser
3. Needing enchanted stuff. Doing this is suicide, but if you really want to, you can track all possible armor enchantments for all possible pieces to recreate the item

In case of 1 and 3, use `replaceitem` to get it into the dispenser